# Is there anywhere that has a large list of phonological rules of Standard American English and/or other dialects?

Tags: american-english, phonology

I'm looking for a giant list of phonological rules of American English. None of the reference grammars that I have looked at appear to include something like this. Any directions anyone could push me in? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by phonological rules? For example, are you interested in patterns of allophonic variation, or phonotactics, or morphophonology?

Comment: @suməlic Primarily allophonic variation.

Comment: @tchrist Not really, many reference grammars would typically contain some sort of section pertaining to phonological rules.

Answer (score 1):

I found a list of "[Rules of English Allophones](http://www.sfu.ca/~alderete/hands/sfu221_lecEnglishAllophones.pdf)" that seems to have been uploaded by [John Alderete](http://anderei.net/about/) of Simon Fraser University. It doesn't seem to say it is specific to American English, but it lists some rules that I don't think are common in British accents, such as the voicing and flapping/tapping of intervocalic alveolar stops before unstressed vowels. The list is based on Peter Ladefoged's *A course in phonetics.*

Comment: The link is dead, but here's a cached version: https://web.archive.org/web/20181123143245/http://www.sfu.ca/~alderete/hands/sfu221_lecEnglishAllophones.pdf